# How to import package correctly in python?

Tags: python

The folder is something like:

```
/workspace
   dosomething.py
   /pkg
      __init__.py
      a.py
      b.py
```

where i've added

```
sys.path.append('/workspace')
import a
a.func()
```

in dosomething.py, and

```
from .a import a
from .b import b
```

in __init__.py. And a.py imports b to use some functions in b. After running, the error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'
```

And the error occurs when runs to import b in a.py. I want to know if i've missed some steps or there is any error in it? Thanks for any reply!

Comment: `from .b import *` will work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre♦ I've tried it but no work

Comment: from pkg import a,b will work

Comment: "And the error occurs when runs to import b in a.py" Can you show us that import statement in a.py?

Comment: @yuki, which command do you start with? Is it something along the lines of `python dosomething.py`?

Comment: @MultiSkill I just execute it in IDE as main

Comment: @Shreyak it still stops at import b in a.py

Comment: are you importing module b in a.py ? i thought u want to load modules a,b in dosomething.py. If you want to load module b in a.py then use `from pkg import b` in a.py

Comment: @Shreyak The problem is i want to import a in dosomething.py while a has imported b. Then the code runs till "import b" in a and reports the error. And besides I dont know if it's okay to modify a given package made by others

Comment: best practice is not to modify other packages but create your own which does added functionality you want. In your case loading module b in a using statement `from pkg import b` in a.py and then loading module a in dosomething.py using `from pkg import a` should work

Comment: @jojo just simply "import b"

Comment: @Shreyak Thanks a lot! It works. But if there exists any simplier and unified method in python to import and use a package derectly?